# Method not found: 'Boolean Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenUtilities.IsRecoverableConfiguration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, web

I have a .NET 6 web API that attempts to validate a JWT Bearer token with the following code:

```
objReturn = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().ValidateToken(strJwtToken,
    new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = objSecurityKey,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    }, out objSecurityToken);
```

This works fine; however, I upgraded my NuGet packages today and now I am receiving the following error for all versions of the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` package starting at version 6.29:

> {"Method not found: 'Boolean
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenUtilities.IsRecoverableConfiguration(Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters,
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.BaseConfiguration,
> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.BaseConfiguration ByRef)'."}

What's weird is that the method appears to still be there as I went to it's NuGet.org page, which linked me to it's source repo on GitHub. This missing method appears to be there - it can be found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens/TokenUtilities.cs), starting on line 203.

Any ideas what is going on and how to fix?

**UPDATE:**

I used the example on how to validate a JWT token from this site: https://jasonwatmore.com/post/2022/01/19/net-6-create-and-validate-jwt-tokens-use-custom-jwt-middleware

Comment: After installing `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`, the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` namespace will be provided, and the `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` package does not need to be installed. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @Chen I am using `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` v6.0.20. When I navigate the package tree, I see `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens` v6.0.24, which is a few versions behind the maximum that I can run. So, this leads me to think that this is not the issue. I have updated my question with how to replicate.

Comment: Hi @J Weezy, I still haven't been able to get your problem. Have you tried using the [repository example](https://github.com/cornflourblue/dotnet-6-registration-login-api) in the link you provided?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Explanation

I have encountered the same problem because one of my dependencies references `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens` in the latest version (e.g. 6.32.1) and another references `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer` or `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` (7.0.x), which in turn reference `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` with a "minimum version" (e.g. >=6.15.1) which depends on `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` which depends on `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens`.

```
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect (7.0.x)
|_ Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (6.15.1) 
   |_ System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt (6.15.1)
      |_ Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens (6.32.1) [explicitly added]
```

The NuGet compatibility check indicates no error, but `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` version 6.15.1 is not compatible with more recent versions of `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens` whose method signatures have changed.

### Solution

Either you can remove the explicit reference to `Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens`.

Otherwise you must explicitly add `System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt` or `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect` NuGet package in the most recent version compatible with your `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.XXX` dependencies.

Comment: That worked, thanks! It is kind of bizarre that the solution compiles with no error. One might think that the compiler would/should reliably check for package dependencies.